# Unable to add a view in MVC 5.2 Application .. Scafolding fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

I am simply trying to add a view for a Action in MVC 5.2 Application by 
right clicking in the Action method 
clicking on Add view
Adding the view name
press ok

I see a visual studio dialogue which says Scaffolding...

However after 30 seconds or so I get this error message.

Error:

> There was an error running the selected code generator: 'Failed to
>   initialize Powershell host. if your Powershell execution policy
>   setting is set to AllSigned, open the Package Manager console to
>   initialize the host first.'

Note: Adding a View from the view folder fails with the same error too..

Answer (score 1):

The issues explained at https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/1638 
are related to the same problem. I was experiencing this issue and solved it by installing VS 2015 update 1 found at: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update1-vs.aspx